# Unfollow/Refollow GitHub Project in CircleCI bungles Webhook

Tags: github, circleci

[**This is a crosspost from circleci's community board.**](https://discuss.circleci.com/t/unfollow-refollow-github-project-in-circleci-bungles-webhook/2743)

When I first follow a GitHub project from inside CircleCI, it creates the webhook for me inside GitHub. After unfollowing the GitHub project in CircleCI, the webhook gets removed (that's expected).

When I refollow the project in CircleCI, I see a new CircleCI deploy key gets added to the GitHub project, however, no new webhook is re-added. I tried recreating the webhook manually in GitHub but not sure what to add for the secret.

Payload URL is: https://circleci.com/hooks/github

Secret: ???

Anyone know if any documentation and/or settings in CircleCI dashboard where this can be obtained?

Comment: Never found any documentation for this. It used to work, now it's dead and I only receive "HTTP 400 Bad Request" responses from this url...